# Hard time having finding element using Css or any other locator in protractor

Tags: protractor

This is how my Html source looks like

```
<div class="pam-tile-left">
<div pam-icon="lock-closed input"></div>
</div>
<div class="pam-tile-content">
<gfp-form-password-field class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" placeholder="Password" validate="true" required="true" ng-model="password">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" type="password" ng-show="!showPassword" ng-model="ngModel" ng-disabled="disabled" required="true" placeholder="Password" name="password" data-validate="true">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-hide" type="text" ng-show="showPassword" ng-model="ngModel" ng-disabled="disabled" required="true" placeholder="Password" data-validate="true">
<a data-ng-click="toggleShowPassword(!showPassword)" href="javascript:void(0)">
<div ng-attr-pam-icon=" {{ showPassword ? 'password-hide' : 'password-show' }}" pam-icon="password-show"></div>
</a>
</gfp-form-password-field>
```

I cannot find a password field to click and enter value, I used element(by.css('.ng-untouched')) but then it doesn't find it as it hasnt been touched, please do help.

Comment: Could you just add an `id` attribute to the password input and then grab it with `element(by.id('<yourId>')`?

Comment: is there any other way? Dev is not here and I dont want to touch it before he is back, coz he changed it in between, first it was fine but now it is breaking up coz of new implementation. I am also new to this so if anyone can tell me new way out ..

Comment: I tried using this - $('gfp-form-password-field input[name="password"]') but it says multiple reference. it is strange, dev doesn't want to use IDs as it is not a good practice as per him, how to fix this?

Comment: meh, thought i had an idea, and now i am confused with both, username and password, are bound to "ngModel". why is this? some angular-schema-something i did miss? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('yourpassword');
```

Answer (score 0):

Talked to dev and added a main parent tag to the query. It was there from start and reason for multiple elements is that we are using same element in two places on same page but in different main parent tag.

this is how my new query looks like - this.rootElement.$('gfp-form-password-field input[name="password"]');