# AngularJS typeahead with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to use protractor to implement some e2e tests.
I'd like to simulate user interaction with the autocomplete typeaheaded control.
I can't find a way to select (click) one element from the autocomplete list.
Some suggestions?

I'm using AngularJSv1.3.3 and Bootstrap v3.3.0.

Comment: try doing it using keyboard keys. You may get some help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410273/how-to-send-keyboard-keys-in-protractor-like-tab

Comment: Thank you. Sending a TAB helped, because I need to select exactly the first element in the list, but I'd like to be able to select whatever element in the list.

Comment: @jojo could you provide a reproduceable example or a link with a similar autocompletion? Thanks.

Comment: This is the link to the [autocomplete](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) and the way I use it:  <code><input required id="city" name="city" type="text" ng-model="City" placeholder="Select" typeahead="city as city.description for city in GetCities($viewValue) | filter:{description:$viewValue}"></code>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
// type into the typeahead
element(by.model('job')).sendKeys('123');

// uib-typeahead uses match in matches...  
element.all(by.repeater('match in matches')).get(0).click();
```